# Google Maps API v2 Android not working on Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2)?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I'm developing an app with Google Maps API v2, I've tested it and it is pretty working on HTC Desire 500, Samsung Galaxy SIII mini and Mediacom Phonepad. But on Nexus 5 (with Android Kitkat 4.4.2) my app crashes when I click the button that opens the "ActivityMap". 
I've also installed the API 19 of Android. Anyone can help me? Every kind of help will be greatly appreciated. If you need my code, just ask me.

```
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406): Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 18406
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at com.example.myapplication.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:53)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the crash log please.

Comment: Check this line 6): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-18 11:21:37.240: E/AndroidRuntime(18406): at com.example.myapplication.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:53). A object is null .

Comment: I had seen it before, but I don't know the reason of this NullPointerException, because it works on every device without Android 4.4.2, only on Nexus 5 the app crashes. So my question is: are Google Maps v2 APIs compatible with Android 4.4.2?